# "О(,) времена, о(,) нравы!": как расставить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Всем известная латинская поговорка "O tempora, o mores" — "О(,) времена, о(,) нравы!" Я вот не знаю: нужна тут запятая после междометия "о" или нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, ни в коем случае. Если только вы не последователь "авторской лексики и пунктуации" в стиле Солжа, которыми (обычно) прикрывается банальная неграмотность и слабый языковой корпус

Comment: Авторская пунктуация здесь ни при чём. Авторские знаки употребляются для акценирования смысловой нагрузки. Здесь для авторской пунктуации условий  нет. Но не согласна, что авторская пунктуация - синоним безграмотности.

Answer (score 3):

"О", как и многие подобные (Ах, Ух, А и проч.), может быть междометием или частицей. При этом именно с О обычно происходит путаница. В первом случае запятая как правило нужна; исключения описаны у Валгиной и у Розенталя, я опускаю. Во втором - нет, исключения - в области авторской пунктуации, как тут было замечено. Отсюда и возможные трудности.

Разберемся, что есть что - и когда используется.
При обращении действительно - усилительная ("величательная") частица.
("О Боже!", "О великий царь Иван Васильевич!"). Аналогично частица может использоваться при восклицании, не являющемся обращением как таковым: "О сколько нам открытий чудных". Здесь "сколько открытий чудных" - ну никак не обращение, но смысл тот же, запятая не нужна. "О" здесь легко заменяется или дополняется усилительной конструкцией "Как...", в нашем случае, например, "как чудны", "как странны". 
Так что это как раз наш случай.

Междометие же выражает самостоятельную мысль или эмоцию, оно всегда под ударением, даже если предшествует существительному или местоимению: "О, дождь!", и относится ко всей фразе.

Так что причин для запятой тут нет никаких.

Comment: Согласна..

Answer (score 1):

Перед обращением могут употребляться частицы о, ах, а и другие. Запятой они от обращения не отделяются.

Comment: Это не обращение.

Comment: Да, наверное. По содержанию больше похоже на риторическое восклицание. Пунктуация та же.