# Нужны ли запятые после междометия в начале строф?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, междометие

О не лети так, жизнь, слегка замедли шаг.
Другие вон живут, неспешны и подробны.
А я живу - мосты, вокзалы, ипподромы.
Промахивая так, что только свист в ушах

О не лети так жизнь, уже мне много лет.
Позволь перекурить, хотя б вон с тем пьянчужкой.
Не мне, так хоть ему, бедняге, посочуствуй.
Ведь у него, поди, и курева то нет.

О не лети так жизнь, мне важен и пустяк.
Вот город, вот театр. Дай прочитать афишу.
И пусть я никогда спектакля не увижу,
Зато я буду знать, что был такой спектакль

О не лети так жизнь, я от ветров рябой.
Мне нужно этот мир как следует запомнить.
А если повезет, то даже и заполнить,
Хоть чьи-нибудь глаза хоть сколь-нибудь собой.

О не лети так жизнь, на миг хоть, задержись.
Уж лучше ты меня калечь, пытай, и мучай.
Пусть будет все - тюрьма, болезнь, несчастный случай.
Я все перенесу, но не лети так, жизнь.

Comment: См. подобный вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/16163/%d0%9e-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5

Answer (score 1):

Это стихотворение Леонида Филатова, но, судя по тому, что на разных сайтах оно опубликовано с разными ошибками, оригинал нам не доступен. Поэтому я позволю себе предложить мой вариант.

"О" может быть междометием или частицей.

См. у [Лопатина:](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=130)

> Примечание. С междометиями (по форме) могут совпадать частицы (см. § 103, примечание). Имеющие усилительное значение частицы, в отличие от междометий, не отделяются знаками от слов, при которых они стоят: — Ну пойди, пойди сюда (Плат.); — Ну надо же! — всё изумлялась Марья (Шукш.); — Ай не узнала ?(Бун.).
>
> Усилительные частицы не имеют ударения, они сливаются со следующими словами, тогда как междометия всегда ударны и потому они отделены от следующих слов паузой. Ср.: — А, Иоська! Помешанный (Пауст.); — А, старые знакомые! — проговорил, хмуро усмехаясь, Галиуллин (Б. Паст.); — Поздно хватились. Ушли... — Куда ? — А дьявол их знает! (Шукш.); — Ну, хотя бы найдите способ уничтожить эти ураганы (Пауст.); — А вы видели? — Ну в кино-то видели же? (Шукш.); Ах, вот и дуб заветный (П.); — О, мир, свернись одним кварталом (Забол.); — О любимые сердцем обманы (Забол.); — Э, сейчас не в этом дело (Булг.).

См. также ответ на нашем сайте: ["О(,) времена, о(,) нравы!": как расставить запятые?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/16163/%d0%9e-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5)

Думаю, "о" является здесь именно междометием и поэтому отделяется запятой.

Есть тут грамматические ошибки: пропущен дефис перед частицей *то*, "потерялась" первая *в* в слове *посочувствуй*.

Кроме этого, я бы многое исправил в пунктуационном оформлении данного стихотворения.

О, не лети так, жизнь! [восклицательный знак] Слегка замедли шаг.
Другие вон живут, неспешны и подробны, [запятая]
А я живу - мосты, вокзалы, ипподромы [убрать точку]
Промахивая так, что только свист в ушах! [восклицательный знак]

О, не лети так, [запятая] жизнь! [восклицательный знак] Уже мне много лет.
Позволь перекурить, хотя б вон с тем пьянчужкой.
Не мне, так хоть ему, бедняге, посочувствуй [добавить букву *в*].
Ведь у него, поди, и курева-то [частица *то* пишется черед дефис] нет.
О, не лети так, [запятая] жизнь! [восклицательный знак] Мне важен и пустяк.
Вот город, вот театр. Дай прочитать афишу.
И пусть я никогда спектакля не увижу,
Зато я буду знать, что был такой спектакль. [точка]

О, не лети так, [запятая] жизнь! [восклицательный знак] Я от ветров рябой.
Мне нужно этот мир как следует запомнить.
А если повезет, то даже и заполнить [убрать запятую]
Хоть чьи-нибудь глаза хоть сколь-нибудь собой.

О, не лети так, [запятая] жизнь! [восклицательный знак] На миг хоть [убрать запятую] задержись.
Уж лучше ты меня калечь, пытай [убрать запятую] и мучай, [запятая]
Пусть будет все: [двоеточие] тюрьма, болезнь, несчастный случай — [тире]
Я все перенесу, но не лети так, жизнь! [восклицательный знак]

Пример с перечислением:

> В несколько минут он мог нарисовать всё, что угодно: человеческую фигуру, животных, деревья, здания - всё выходило у него характерно и живо (Бек.).
>   ([Однородные члены с обобщающими словами](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook142/01/part-022.htm))

Comment: "Ведь у него поди" — здесь "поди" вводное и обособляется запятыми.

Comment: @grizzly Согласен, исправляю.

Comment: @М_Г Вот, нашлось стихотворение с более-менее "приличной" пунктуацией. Большинство Ваших поправок здесь присутствует. https://45parallel.net/leonid_filatov/ne_leti_tak_zhizn.html

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Спасибо, хорошая находка!